How do I update odoo in docker from 16.0 to 16.4
I use docker to be able to use odoo 16 (hub.docker.com/layers/library/odoo). I am using the latest available image: 16.0-20240603. But there is already version 16.4. Since it contains some important changes, how can I use odoo in version 16.4 as a docker image? Do I have to assemble this myself or should it be included in the docker image automatically? odoo --version returns Odoo Server 16.0-20240603 as version.
